# Expression Language in JSP not working

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am new to JSP and using Expression language. I am using Eclipse Galileo with version 2.5 and Tomcat 6 server . I just want to ask that my simple Expression Language is not printing the vale like if i write `${1>2}` which suppose to give false but it is displaying  `${1>2}` only when it renders the page. But when i am using `<c:out value="${1>2}"/>` it is printing false correctly. I think there is an issue with tag library. Please kindly suggest me the reason for this i am giving a sample code for this so that you can understand where I am going wrong:-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Expression Language Example</title>
</head>
<body>

Is 1 greater than 2 using cout  :<c:out value="${1>2}"/>

Is 1 greater than 2 without using cout: ${1>2}
</body>
</html>
```

**Update** as per the answers, here is more information:

I am showing my `web.xml` how it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ScriptLessJsp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ElServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ElServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.El.ElServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ElServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ElServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Collections</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Collections</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.El.Collections</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Collections</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/go</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And in my lib folder I have added only `jstl.jar` so that i can make use of `<c:out>` tag to display but my EL for template text is not working.

Answer (score 58):

I'm quoting from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721518/el-expressions-wont-executed-in-tomcat-5-5-but-working-in-tomcat-6-0-20/1721665#1721665) I provided before to the problem of EL not working:

> With other words, the EL expression doesn't get evaluated? That can have one or more of the following causes:
>
> 1. Application server in question doesn't support JSP 2.0.
> 2. The `web.xml` is not declared as Servlet 2.4 or higher.
> 3. The `@page` is configured with `isELIgnored=true`.
> 4. The web.xml is configured with `<el-ignored>true</el-ignored>` in `<jsp-config>`.

In your particular case, EL works in taglibs, but not in template text, so I suspect it's caused by point 2. Ensure that your `web.xml` is declared as **at least** Servlet 2.4. As Tomcat 6.0 supports Servlet 2.5, I would recommend to declare your `web.xml` as Servlet 2.5:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="Your_WebApp_ID"
    version="2.5">

    <!-- Here you go. -->

</web-app>
```

Another rare cause I've seen on this is that there's a collision with EL JAR's in the classpath. Ensure that you have **not** copied any appserver-specific JAR files into your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` or, more worse, the `JRE/lib`.

As you're already using Eclipse and Tomcat, I would review the development steps you used for this all. Ensure that you're using "Eclipse for Java **EE** developers" and that you've integrated the Tomcat instance in Eclipse's *Servers* view and that you've created a *Dynamic Web Project* set to "Servlet 2.5" which makes use of the Tomcat instance. This way everything should go automagically (Eclipse will take appserver's libraries in the build path itself and autogenerate a Servlet 2.5 compliant `web.xml`).

**Update:** as per your update: those `com.servlet.El` servlets look suspicious. What exactly do they do? Parsing EL? Remove them and retry.

Comment: I also noticed that the servlet shouldn't be named "jsp", "default", "ssi", "cgi" - naming it like that will also break JSP functionality as these are built-in Tomcat servlets.

Comment: @BalusC.. I got a same problem. I could solve it with your web.xml modification solution.. Thank you soooo much..

Comment: also it makes sence to add <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %> that only helped to me!!!! Tomcat 7, java 8

Comment: Yep. My web.xml version was 2.3. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 27):

Setting `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` at the top of the page helped to me. Don't know why it was the root of the problem in my case. not clear why yet

Comment: Your solution is just awesome. After trying lots of other option. Yours is worked for me

Comment: Thanks. It worked in my case.

Comment: Oh my god. this worked:) Thanks a lot for saving my time.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I generated a webapp by maven archetype generator, I use maven-archetype-webapp. I need to change two things:

1. in web.xml, change the head to:

   ```html
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5">
   ```
2. by default, eclipse generated jsp file with head:

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   ```

Just remove it.

Comment: I had the problem in an old Tomcat 5.5 and solved it by going from web-app 2.5 to 2.4

Comment: solved with 2_5.xsd and version="2.5" many thanks

Answer (score 4):

[BalusC covers it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working/2168974#2168974), but I'll add these comments:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

The [JSTL TLD](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) namespace should include a "jsp" (as above). Given this namespace error may be due to following old instructions, check the most recent documentation to ensure you haven't included any obsolete libraries in `WEB-INF/lib`. A number of technologies that used to be separate are now included in the container (the EL language being one).

*As an aside, I would generally use keywords like [`gt` instead of `>` and `lt` instead of `<`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/syntax/2.0/syntaxref207.html#1010522) - this is friendlier to XML and its ilk.*

Answer (score 0):

I've had the problem that with the line `<!DOCTYPE html>` in my JSP, the tomcat started with eclipse didn't interpret the EL correctly. Using the war and copying it to the `webapps` folder and then starting tomcat with the commandline did the job.

So obviously eclipse tomcat plugin has a problem with *`<!DOCTYPE html>`*?!