# jsp:include not working with Expression Language (JSP version 2.5, EL enabled)

Tags: jsp, include, expression

I've read: 
[Expression Language in JSP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working)
but it's slightly different.

Using EL for referencing file works fine like the one below.

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/global.css"/>
```

However when try to use JSP include tag with EL expression:

```
<jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/header.jsp" />
```

This returns http 500.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: File &quot;/head_first/header.jsp&quot; not found
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:527)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I also made sure to enable EL too.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %>
```

My tomcat version is 6.0 and web.xml defines that JSP is 2.5

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
```

Does anyone know why EL not working ONLY when used in jsp:include tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EL is working fine. The context path is been printed. But you don't need prefix `jsp:include page` with the context path. It's already implicitly relative to the context path. It is namely not possible to include files from other contexts. Your approach will end up in a file from `/head_first/head_first/include.jsp` being included which thus doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the tip,
I'm little confused here. I thought if I want to include a jsp file, something like <jsp:include page="foo.jsp" /> is used. Could you be more specific how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Oh I think I got it. <jsp:include page="include.jsp" />

Comment: Yes, you don't need to prefix it with the context path.