# Spring MVC and JSP - can not pass data from controller to jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, gwt

I have a GWT Application with Spring MVC support. I've defined a spring controller:
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("index");
        result.addObject("message", "hello, world!");
        return result;
    }
}
```

and this controller returns simple jsp-based view:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Они с нами</title>

    <link href="<%=getServletContext().getContextPath()%>/style/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link href="<%=getServletContext().getContextPath()%>/style/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
    <link href="<%=getServletContext().getContextPath()%>/style/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%=getServletContext().getContextPath()%>/stub/stub.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p style="display:none">${message}</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

URL mapping and redirecting to the view works OK, but,

```
<p style="display:none">${message}</p>
```

does not works - it just prints ${message}

Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <!-- Reads request input using UTF-8 encoding -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index/</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and my springMvc-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.onisnami.site.server.controllers"/>
</beans>
```

Also pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.onisnami</groupId>
  <artifactId>onisnami-site</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

  <properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.1.1</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.gwt.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.customware.gwt.dispatch</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-dispatch</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <!-- <goal>test</goal>
              <goal>i18n</goal>
              <goal>generateAsync</goal> -->
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
          documentation at codehaus.org -->
        <configuration>
          <runTarget>stub.html</runTarget>
          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

A spent all day in the searching of solution, but it still does not work. Help me please.
Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working

Comment: Why are you using <%=getServletContext().getContextPath()%>/style/reset.css instead of <c:url value="/style/reset.css"/> ?

Answer (score 4):

You are correct, since you are defining expressions

```
  ${Anything between this is expression}
```

You need to include

```
  <%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

isELIgnored is false, i.e Expressions are taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is found:

it is needed to add following lines:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

At the begin of the JSP file