# Print a value using JSP and Expression Language (EL)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet, and I want to print some data from the servlet with a JSP file, and I have to use compulsory the Expression Language.

I have this code in the servlet:

```
String saludo="hi";  
req.setAttribute("exito",saludo);
```

And I have this in my JSP file:

```
${exito}
```

And I also tried with this:

```
${requestScope.exito}
```

But when I try to see it with my browser (Google Chrome), instead of seeing `hi`, I see

```
${exito}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: duplicate of [Expression Language in JSP not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working)

Comment: try JSTL include <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> then try <c:out value="${exito}"></c:out>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are sending information to the JSP you need to dispacth the current request to the JSP, I try the above code and I don't have any problem, this is my code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String saludo="hi";  
    req.setAttribute("exito",saludo);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("MyPage.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

And this is the code for MyPage.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${exito}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem was with the Dispatcher, i have it on another way, i tried your code and it worked fine. Thanks again