# Enable EL in JSP

Tags: jsp, el

Is there any solution for enabling EL in JSP. For now, I have to add `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` in all pages. It looks so messy.

I tried add config in web.xml like this

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Whats your j2ee version ? And have you added this tags `<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>`

Comment: And also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working/2168974#2168974) could help you

Comment: My j2ee version is 3.0

Comment: EL is enabled by default if it is supported. What makes you think it isn't working? I assume you mean you are trying to use EL 3.0. Which container are you using?

Comment: @MarkThomas There's no EL 3.0. The lastest version is 2.2. After I fallback to use container version 2.4, the EL works

Comment: @Bobkhin Yes there is an EL 3.0. I was a member of the Expert Group that wrote the specification. You aren't being very clear about what you are doing. Again, which container are you using? Additionally, how are you "falling back to container version 2.4" and from what version are you falling back?

Comment: @MarkThomas I'm newbie in Java so it's hard for me to explain. Here's my current web-app in web.xml `<web-app id="portalAlpha" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">`. The previous, I used `version=2.5` and `version=3.0` and the EL didnt work.

Comment: For the third time, "Which container are you using." You also still haven't explained why you think EL isn't working. You really need to read this http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html