# Why this JSTL foreach doesn't function?

Tags: jquery, jsp, foreach, jstl

I have a servlet with:

```
request.setAttribute("agenzieList",businessLogic.findAllAgenzia());
rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/prenotazioneAg.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

And in my jsp I want to use my list with the select option.
I'm new with JSTL and I tried so:

```
<select name="agenzia" onChange="toggleSubmit('d',this)">
 <c:forEach items="${agenzieList}" var="agenzia">
  <option value="${agenzia.idAgenzia}">${agenzia.nome}</option>
 </c:forEach>
</select>`
```

If I write only `${agenzieList}` in my jsp I can see my full list with every element. 
But my selection box remains empty. So the problem I think is in the foreach syntax.
Where is my error? I don't understand.

Comment: try this alone `<option value="${agenzia}">${agenzia}</option>`

Comment: I tried it but doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you sure that the list is not empty ?

Comment: Yes, if I put ${agenzieList} in my jsp, I can see all the list elements.

Comment: please try printing this `<c:out value="${'test , &'}"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the necessary `jstl` tags,

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Also make sure you that you your application supports Expression Language.

For info about EL [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working)

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. I'm too new. Thanks a lot

Comment: No issues . happy to help :)