# How to print the message on server using session object in my controller class

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, session, spring-boot

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@Scope("session")
public class HomeController {

    private String sessionUser;

    public void setSessionUser(String sessionUser) {
        this.sessionUser = sessionUser;
    }

    public String getSessionUser() {
        return this.sessionUser;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/profile" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String profilePage(Model model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    {
        User session = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("name");
        if(session != null)
        {
            model.addAttribute("userInfo", "mklyohngsd");
            return "profile";
        }else
         model.addAttribute("userInfo", "logged out!!");
        return "home";

    }
}
```

> want to print userinfo in my server console,this model.addAttribute() is not working
>
> > In jsp pages i used **${userinfo}** to print,but its only printing {userinfo} not the details.
> >
> > > I am new to jsp and spring please help.

Comment: Have you set this `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%> at your jsp ?! `

Comment: Try with `${requestScope.userinfo}`

Comment: The problem is that you are not using at all EL, some config is missing se here [Expression Language in JSP not working] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working)

Comment: add the web.xml you are using.

Comment: I added but not working