# JSTL represent like text

Tags: html, database, jsp, jstl, el

**A**. In my jsp file I'm using jstl code like this :

```
<c:if test="${SURVEY_Q_LIST.IMG_FILE_SEQ != null && SURVEY_Q_LIST.IMG_FILE_SEQ != ''}">
  <div class="survey-question-img">
    <img src="${SURVEY_Q_LIST.FILE_PATH}" alt="">
  </div>
</c:if>
```

**B**. It works like this :

```
<div class="survey-question-img">
   <img src="https://test.com/resources/test.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

---

I input **A** code in database and I select database and call it using el tag

```
${jspCode}   

 /*
  jspCode = 
  <c:if test="${SURVEY_Q_LIST.IMG_FILE_SEQ != null && SURVEY_Q_LIST.IMG_FILE_SEQ != ''}">
    <div class="survey-question-img">
       <img src="${SURVEY_Q_LIST.FILE_PATH}" alt="">
    </div>
 </c:if>
 */
```

But my Website read that code as text.(**jstl and el tag is not working**)
Like this

[image]

**please help It works like B**

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168832/expression-language-in-jsp-not-working/33722970) post?

Comment: It already works like that

Comment: So what doesn't work ? Also what do you mean by `input whole No.1's jsp code with jstl..` ?

Comment: @Swati please read again...! I edit my Question

Answer (score 0):

JSP is normally translated to Java code by your servlet container. Your `${jspCode}` will be translated to something that looks like `out.write(jspCode)`. The contents of `jspCode` will be printed as-is. (simply like `System.out.print(jspCode)` in Java)

If you need dynamic JSP you have to play around with a JSP compiler and do the work yourself.