# ModelAttributes not accessible on jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Created a new Spring MVC project using MAven and Im having a problem where the modelAttributes are not getting substituted on the jsp page. For eg.,

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>

Hello Worlds ${location} is ${weathers}
<c:out value="${location}"/>
```

displays

```
Hello Worlds ${location} is ${weathers}
${location}
```

instead of

```
Hello Worlds Omaha is Cold
Omaha
```

I'm guessing I'm missing a jar, I have the following in the mvn dependency list :

> ```
>    <dependency>
>        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
>        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
>        <version>1.1.2</version>
>    </dependency>
>    <dependency>
>        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
>        <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_2.4_spec</artifactId>
>        <version>1.1.1</version>
>    </dependency>
>    <dependency>
>        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
>        <version>2.4</version>
>        <scope>provided</scope>
>    </dependency>
>    <dependency>
>        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
>        <version>2.0.7</version>
>    </dependency>
>    <dependency>
>        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
>        <version>2.5.5</version>
>    </dependency>
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I'm quoting from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721518/el-expressions-wont-executed-in-tomcat-5-5-but-working-in-tomcat-6-0-20/1721665#1721665) I provided before to the problem of EL not working:

> With other words, the EL expression doesn't get evaluated? That can have one or more of the following causes:
>
> 1. Application server in question doesn't support JSP 2.0.
> 2. The `web.xml` is not declared as Servlet 2.4 or higher.
> 3. The `@page` is configured with `isELIgnored=true`.
> 4. The web.xml is configured with `<el-ignored>true</el-ignored>` in `<jsp-config>`.

In your particular case, 1) can be scratched. 3) and 4) are too obvious to be overseen, so that can likely be scratched as well. Left behind point 2). Your `web.xml` is apparently declared with an older version. Ensure that your `web.xml` is declared as **at least** Servlet 2.4:

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <!-- Here you go. -->

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your servlet container is using JSP pre-2.0, where EL is ignored by default. Check what has been bundled with it.

Anyway, you have to specify the following:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```