# How can I create dynamic sources (src) for link and script tags using jsp and javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, dynamic, hyperlink

I have a jsp file that passes a parameter to another jsp file.  This parameter is of type string and takes the value of a folder name in the web server path (i.e. http://myserver.com/Page/Folder_Name).

In the second jsp file, I have quite a few js and css files I'm attaching using script and link tags, respectively.  I need to make their paths relative to the parameter passed.  My thought-process is construct dynamic source (src) paths using jsp tags and javascript.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Folder_Name/css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Folder_Name/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Except Folder_Name will be dynamic, utilizing JSP somehow.  At least, that's my mindset.
The question is how may I accomplish this?  I'm open to other suggestions, with the initial condition of said parameter is passed to the second jsp page.

Thank you.

Comment: How, exactly, is the parameter passed? `<jsp:param>` inside a `<jsp:include>`? It would be very helpful if you could show some code.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm passing it via querystring and retrieving it using request.getParameter("FolderName")

Answer (score 2):

Why do this with JavaScript? If it's already a JSP page, you're already doing server-side processing, so it seems like you'd want to use Java. E.g., once you have the folder name in a variable (say, `folderName`), just do this to output the links:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=folderName%>/css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=folderName%>/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

(Note the `<%=folderName%>` bit, which runs on the server and outputs the value of the server-side `folderName` variable.) Or if you're using a container that supports the [JSP expression language](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html), use `${folderName}` instead:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${folderName}/css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="${folderName}/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

You certainly *could* use JavaScript for the task, if you want, but I'm not sure it makes sense. You could use Rhino (JavaScript for the JVM) on the server, of course. If you're talking client-side, you'd basically have to echo the folder name into a place where the client-side JavaScript can find it (so, output it to a dynamically-generated global variable — `<script>var folderName = '<%=folderName%>';</script>` for example — or to a hidden `input`, or whatever), and then have your JavaScript add the necessary script tags via `document.createElement`, set their `src`, and append them to the `head` or `body` (doesn't matter where), but it seems a very round-about way to do it if you're already doing server-side processing.

Comment: Ew, scriptlets? `s/<%=folderName%>/${folderName}`

Comment: @MattBall: Sure, **if** he's using JSTL, he could do it that way.

Comment: Thank you very much to you both.  This is a great solution.  The reason I brought up JavaScript is I am referencing paths in a separate js file and I would like to make those relative, as well.  If I should post another question for that, then I will delete this comment and do so.  Thank you again.

Comment: @user717236: If you need the folder path client-side as well, you can still do the `<script>var folderName = '<%=folderName%>';</script>` or `<script>var folderName = '${folderName}';</script>` thing (as long as the folder names are such that that will result in a valid JavaScript string literal, which seems likely in this specific case). Then you can use that 'folderName' variable in your client-side code. Downside is that it's a global, and I tend to shy away from globals, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: you don't need the JSTL to use the JSP EL.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks, I've fixed it. You need to be using *something*. Just doing it in a vanilla JSP page doesn't work (at least not under Tomcat6). I did try it, in case I was in the process of learning something new. :-)

Comment: EL is supported in template text since JSP 2.0 (2003).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: No you don't. See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html. That's for JEE1.4. The current version is 6. Quote: "EL expressions can be used: In static text; In any standard or custom tag attribute that can accept an expression. The value of an expression in static text is computed and inserted into the current output."

Comment: @JBNizet: I say again: I tried it, it didn't work in Tomcat6, which supposedly supports JSP 2.1. So there are perfectly good JSP environments in which it doesn't work out-of-the-box. This is, at best, a *very minor point* in the context of the question. More to the point, my edit makes it perfectly clear that he can use it if his environment supports it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: please calm down. It isn't a critic on your answer. It's just an information for you: EL is supported in JSP without the JSTL for 8 years, and scriptlets are considered bad practice for even longer. Just because it doesn't work on your Tomcat install doesn't mean my statements are false. I even linked to an Oracle tutorial. And I tested it on a fresh new Tomcat 6 install (where it works out of the box).

Comment: @JBNizet: I'm perfectly calm. I'm just giving *you* information: It doesn't necessarily work out of the box with a fresh Tomcat6 install (mine is also quite fresh, installed from the Apache tarball about two weeks ago). I'm not doing anything to disable it. But again, my point is that this is a completely minor nit being picked, and that doing so serves basically no purpose. The answer now includes both scriptlets (which you may not like, but which are perfectly fine) and JSP expressions. The OP can use whatever works in his/her environment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: you must disable it somehow, probably by declaring a wrong webapp version in the web.xml. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721518/el-expressions-wont-executed-in-tomcat-5-5-but-working-in-tomcat-6-0-20. Or you're doing the wrong test : ${foo} isn't equivalent to <%= foo %>. It's equivalent to <%= pageContext.findAttribute("foo") %>. And I'm just discussing this point because I thought you would learn something interesting, which is the point of this web site, AFAIK.

Comment: @JBNizet: That's probably it (and it wouldn't necessarily be the "wrong" version; perhaps the code being run is written to the earlier standard, old legacy stuff). My point being: The OP could easily be doing the same thing, and again it's *entirely* tangential and covered in the answer as soon as Matt pointed it out. But thank you for the info, useful to know.