# JSP include param not parsing?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, include

I am using JSP includes in a project and have recently set up my environment on another computer. But now when I serve the project on Tomcat I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.io.FileNotFoundException: The requested resource (/rootprojectlevel/secure/${param.includeIt}) is not available
```

The code that I have in my jsp looks like this:

```
<jsp:include page="sideBar.jspf" >
    <jsp:param name="includeIt" value="correspondingmenu.jspf" />
</jsp:include>
```

In sideBar.jspf I have the following which gets the parameter passed from that first JSP include:

```
<jsp:include  page="${param.includeIt}" />
```

Maybe the JSP expression language isnt getting evaluated?

This issue only happened after creating my new environment in Eclipse, so maybe something with Tomcat is not configure correctly for JSP's? Or maybe my project path is not included? I've been racking my brain but can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: share `sideBar.jspf` as well. How are you using it?

Comment: See if this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1721665/738746

Comment: what is the location of `correspondingmenu.jspf` in the project or war file?

Comment: The correspondingmenu.jspf is at /rootprojectlevel/secure/ as are all of the jsp/jspf files other than the login.

Comment: so all three files are in same folder?

Comment: Yeah all in the same folder.

Comment: @BheshGurung I think that is on the right track, that the el isn't being parsed. But my web.xml in the project looks fine, I tried changing the servlet version to 2.4 with no effect. Gonna look at the dependencies next to see if something is conflicting or not the right dependency.